# List Wordpress Terms Including Parent

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm having issues listing terms of a custom taxonomy. Actually I can list the terms that contain posts with their parents.

Here's an example: 
I have products in

**Boots**

-Kid's

-Men's

-Women's

**Men**

-Boots

-Jeans

-Outerwear

-Shirts

So ideally what I'd like to do list the terms exactly how they are with parent and children if they contain posts.

You can see where I am right now here http://demo.rineholdwesternwear.com/product_type/boots-kids/

Current Code

```
<?php 

$terms = get_terms( 'product_type' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>' . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just go this little snippet of an answer from the [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158787/listing-child-terms-of-parent-term).

I think this is what you want:-

```
<?php

$queried_object = get_queried_object('term');
  $term_parent = $queried_object->parent;
  $tax = $queried_object->taxonomy;

$args = array(
  'parent' => $term_parent,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  );

$terms = get_terms( $tax, $args );
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
    } 
}
?>
```

If this doesn't answer your question then your best bet would be to ask the question over on the WordPress StackExchange as you have a better chance of getting an answer

Comment: No this is for getting the terms from within a taxonomy using the page you're on as the parent. I want to use it to create a sidebar menu of all the terms within my custom taxonomy. I can display them all I just want to organize them in an organized way with the parents and children like a file tree.